# access value in array of class by name

Tags: arrays, vb.net

i am trying to access a specific status of a specific device such as device1.status.status1 to get the value of status1
the array the following

```
ID = 1
DeviceName = device1
Device_ID = 234
Status_array()
     1, status1, statusvalue1
     2, status2, statusvalue2
     etc
ID =2 
DeviceName = device2
Device_ID  =567
Status_array()
    3, status3, statusvalue3
    4, status4, statusvalue4
     etc
```

i hope the title is enough here is what i have
an array of devices that is built from a dataset of devices and statuses(all statuses for all device) there are around 25 devices each having 10-15 different statuses

here is the code i use to create the array, it iterates each device in the device table, then iterates through status table and adds the status array to the device array (this code works) i can set a breakpoint and see the array contains the proper data i just can figure out how to access it

```
Public Sub LoadDevices()
    Dim foundRows() As Data.DataRow
    foundRows = MyDevicesDS.Tables("devices").Select()

    For Each item In foundRows
        Dim deviceitem As New G2SWebService.DevicesClass
        Dim id As Integer = item("ID")
        Dim DeviceName As String = item("DeviceName")
        Dim Device_ID As Integer = item("Device_ID")

        deviceitem.Id = item("ID")
        deviceitem.DeviceName = item("DeviceName")
        deviceitem.Device_ID = item("Device_ID")
        Dim statusrows() As Data.DataRow
        Dim statusarray As New List(Of statusClass)()
        statusrows = MyDevicesDS.Tables("status").Select("ParentDeviceID = " + item("ID").ToString)
        For Each statusrow In statusrows
            Dim statusitem As New G2SWebService.statusClass
            statusitem.ID = statusrow("ID")
            statusitem.name = statusrow("name")
            statusitem.StrValue = statusrow("StrValue")

            statusarray.Add(statusitem)
            Console.WriteLine("jjj")

        Next
        deviceitem.status = statusarray
        Device_Array.Add(deviceitem)
        Console.WriteLine("kkk")
    Next
End Sub
```

here are the classes i am using

```
Public Class DevicesClass
    Public Id As Integer
    Public DeviceName As String
    Public Device_ID As Integer
    Public status As New List(Of statusClass)
End Class

Public Class statusClass
    Public ID As Integer
    Public name As String
    Public StrValue As String
    Public valueType As String
End Class
```

this is about as far as i got

```
For Each item In Device_Array
        Dim device As String = item.DeviceName
        Dim deviceId As String = item.Device_ID
        Dim statusEnabled As String = item.status.
            'the above line Is where i need To Get the value Of statusEnabled
    Next
```

Comment: `Dim statusEnabled As String = item.status.FirstOrDefault(Function(st) st.ID = 1).StrValue`

Comment: i added that and get "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: You probably don't have any `status` with `statud.ID = 1`. Add a nullable result if `FirstOrDefault()` returns `nothing` (no matches are found): `Dim statusEnabled As String = item.status.FirstOrDefault(Function(st) st.ID = 1)?.StrValue`. The result will be `nothing` when there are no results.

Comment: perfect, i also added a check to see if item.status.count >0  `Enabled = item.status.FirstOrDefault(Function(st) st.name = "statusEnabled")?.StrValue`

Comment: You could of course use a dictionary(Of String, G2SWebService.DevicesClass) and use the device name as the string to add. This would of course require all the device names to be different.